# Sketch makes everything blurred

Tags: sketch-app

I've noticed that everything I seem to export or local share on my machine from Sketch seems to be blurred, even if I am looking at it, at that size.

I'm on a MBP Retina would that make any difference? I know I'm doing something stupid. If you don't understand what I mean I'll export and show you.

Comment: It seems that you didn't set export at @2x. This tutorial explains exporting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dpk1XYlFzOs

Comment: Hi andy, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please include a screenshot of what you mean? That will make it way easier to give you a good answer. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to go there (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: So when I export the dartboard at @ 1x it's blurry, then @2x it's not so bad. In the past though even @ 2x is blurry. I know i'm being stupid somewhere along the line.  How do I upload images to show you?

For example when I make an artboard for Dribbble, should I make it 400x300 then export x2 to get required image size of 800x600? Thanks again!

Comment: Here's how you **upload a photo**: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C7gIV.png 
You can always use http://www.imgur.com and paste the link here